# How to disable word background transparency only for one View Layer on Eevee

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, eevee-render-engine

Eevee doesn't have the Environment pass, so I'm looking for a solution to have one View Layer with the World background and another View layer with the background transparent to composite on top of the previous one.

If I activate the world background transparency it makes the sky layer also transparent and if I deactivate it the second layer doesn't have an alpha channel.

Is there any more recent method to do this in Eevee?

The purpose of this rendering is to an animation, not a still.
My world comes from an add-on called "Real-Sky" but you can imagine it like the standard blender sky texture.

This is a rendering with only one view layer, it's just all in one:
[image]

Now I'm aiming to a bit more control over the Sky, Background and Foreground and as such I ideally would want something like this:
[image]

... This screen was achieved by rendering the layers individually and hand activating and deactivating "world transparency" on the render panel.

Comment: Not sure what your goal is, but you can duplicate the scene and set the duplicate to have a transparent background. Then in the compositor add an additional Input->Render Layers and set the scene. Both Scenes will be rendered and available for compositing.

Comment: Hey Rob! Thanks for your fast reply! You're talking sence, it may work that way indeed, although I'm a bit worried with time and memory increases. Allow me to clarify a bit too, I'll try to add new pictures on the first topic with further explanations.

Comment: Hey again Rob! Your solution of using 2 scenes as worked and solved the issue. I only had to make one new scene and add the same world to it. As soon I change the world in the main scene (the one with transparency activated) it updates to the new scene (with no transparency). Thanks!